# Extracting OSRM PBF file using Docker osrm/osrm-backend image?

Tags: open-source-routing-machine, docker

I have installed Docker Desktop for Windows and I'm trying to extract the California PBF file. My Docker instance has 16 GB of RAM.

Is more RAM needed to extract California?

```
PS D:\Datasets\TigerLine Shapefiles\06> docker run -t -v "$(pwd):/data" osrm/osrm-backend osrm-extract -p /opt/car.lua /data/california-latest.osm.pbf
[info] Parsed 0 location-dependent features with 0 GeoJSON polygons
[info] Using script /opt/car.lua
[info] Input file: california-latest.osm.pbf
[info] Profile: car.lua
[info] Threads: 4
[info] Parsing in progress..
[info] input file generated by osmium/1.8.0
[info] timestamp: 2019-01-21T21:15:02Z
[info] Using profile api version 4
[info] Found 3 turn restriction tags:
[info]   motorcar
[info]   motor_vehicle
[info]   vehicle
[info] Parse relations ...
[info] Parse ways and nodes ...
[info] Using profile api version 4
[info] Using profile api version 4
[info] Using profile api version 4
[info] Parsing finished after 78.5229 seconds
[info] Raw input contains 95656519 nodes, 8693941 ways, and 4099 relations, 33549 restrictions
[info] RAM: peak bytes used: 3181412352
[error] Problem opening file: /data/california-latest.osrm :  (possible cause: "Permission denied") (at include/storage/tar.hpp:37)
```

Answer (score 1):

When using PowerShell on Windows the proper command needs to have quotes around the paths:

```
docker run -t -v "$(pwd):/data" osrm/osrm-backend osrm-extract -p "/opt/car.lua" "/data/california-latest.osm.pbf"
```